# QtQml conversion for Non-QObject types

Tags: c++, qt

Since QtScript is deprecated in Qt5.5, I have to migrate to QtQml JS engine. I can't find any articles, how to migrate painless.

In old code for value-based types (not derived from QObject) was a possibility to create wrapper, by deriving from QScriptable. In QtQml there are no QScriptable. but I know, that they have similar conversion [qml basic types](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-typesystem-basictypes.html), like

```
Point     <-> QPoint
Rectangle <-> QRect
```

I think, it should be possible to register value-type with some conversion functions to wrapper and vice-verse.

Do you know how to achieve it?

Comment: a fast way could be `QPoint q_point(point.x, point.y)` (with `Point point`) and so on, not so much elegant, but it will work

Comment: From the page you linked: `Currently only QML modules which are provided by Qt may provide their own basic types, however this may change in future releases of Qt QML.`

Comment: If you look into the internals of Qt Quick implementation, you'll see how to do it :)

Comment: Is it a joke? They have it in js-runtime, with private export... I don't want to hack qt so deep :)